# What is the CakePHP equivalent of WordPress' header.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp, header

I need to edit something in the header of a web site running on CakePHP.  I am not familiar with CakePHP and this is the first time I have used it!

Can you tell me where I would go to make this change?  If I was using WordPress, I would go and edit the header.php file inside of the wpcontent/themes/currenttheme folder.

What is the name of the file that I am looking for in CakePHP where I would make this type of change?

Thanks for your help!

Laura

Comment: Check `view/layouts/default.ctp`.

Comment: Frameworks tend to have a single layout PHP file, rather than the way Wordpress does it, which is to have a separate header/footer. I tend to regard Wordpress's approach as a bit legacy since modern IDEs/texteditors regard unclosed tags as having errors.

Comment: Also look for echo $this->element('somelement') which would be located at View/Elements/somelement.ctp

Comment: Search your files for something that is already in the header. As mentioned, it could in the layout, an element. It could also be in  a view, a view block, a custom layout, etc.  Search is the most direct way to find the file.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hacking blindly around in something you do not understand and probably causing more problems than solving issues I really recommend you to read the basics about the CakePHP framework: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html

Also your question implies that you very likely do not have an idea of MVC, so read about it also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

If you do not want to go for best practice jump directly to the view section of the book that explains how CakePHP handles templates: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html

Do not compare the (IMHO horrible) Wordpress code from the stone age of php with a modern application architecture and modern software design principles which you will find in all up to date frameworks.